# Edit header and footer only for "customer-on-hold-order" email notifications in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, email-notifications

I tried to edit the header and footer of emails of my store, but I'm only able to edit if it goes directly to the template of **ALL** emails.

I also tried to copy the [email-header.php](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/3611d4643791bad87a0d3e6e73e031bb80447417/plugins/woocommerce/templates/emails/email-header.php) and [email-footer.php](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/3611d4643791bad87a0d3e6e73e031bb80447417/plugins/woocommerce/templates/emails/email-footer.php) to my child theme and nothing happens.

Since that the template [customer-on-holder-order](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/3611d4643791bad87a0d3e6e73e031bb80447417/plugins/woocommerce/templates/emails/customer-on-hold-order.php) have listed the code

```php
/*
 * @hooked WC_Emails::email_header() Output the email header
 */
do_action( 'woocommerce_email_header', $email_heading, $email ); ?>

...

/*
 * @hooked WC_Emails::email_footer() Output the email footer
 */
do_action( 'woocommerce_email_footer', $email );
```

How can I find/edit this? Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is correct that the `woocommerce_email_header` and the `woocommerce_email_footer` action hook  occur in multiple template files.

However, to target a specific email you can use `$email->id`, since `$email` is passed to both hooks as an argument

So you get:

```php
// Header
function action_woocommerce_email_header( $email_heading, $email ) {    
    // Target
    if ( $email->id == 'customer_on_hold_order' ) {  
        echo 'customer on hold order header';
    }
} 
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_header', 'action_woocommerce_email_header', 10, 2 );

// Footer
function action_woocommerce_email_footer( $email ) {
    // Target
    if ( $email->id == 'customer_on_hold_order' ) {  
        echo 'customer on hold order footer';
    }   
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_footer', 'action_woocommerce_email_footer', 10, 1 );
```

---

Code goes in `functions.php` file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works in Wordpress 5.8.1 & WooCommerce 5.8.0

Comment: So, this mean that the I need to change all emails manually. I can't use a template to change all emails using the current hook for header and footer?

Comment: @LuísCosta It depends on what you specifically want to do. Overwriting template files with if/else conditions can be an option. Another option is to do it via hooks (see my answer).